# How Exporting PhpMyAdmin data in Zipped or gzipped

Tags: database, importexport, magento-1.9.2

[image]

I am a learner with Magento i have created dummy website on my localhost Xmapp server. Now i want to move it to live server but when i am exporting Mysql data base it is directly downloaded in sql and for importing data in cpanel i required databse in .sql.zipped or .sql.gzipped. Please guide me how can i import my data in cpanel.

[image: screenshot attached]

Comment: you can  import data in sql file format. no need to in zip format

Comment: But when i am uploading sql file its showing error.

Comment: what error its show ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE25d.jpg please refer the link also screenshot uploaded

Answer (score 1):

Your exported sql file is corrupted.

Try exporting the database using **mysqldump**

Open xampp window and click on **shell** button as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

After clicking on shell button, it will open a shell window.

Enter following command in the shell.

> mysqldump -u USERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME > db_backup.sql

You will get your sql file in your xampp folder

```
e.g. D:/xampp/db_backup.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

after enter command it is asking for password as for my memory i am not created any password for database.[image: after enter command it is asking for password as for my memory i am not created any password for database.]

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window and in your MySQL path. After enter the next command with your own data:

- sudo mysqldump -h HOSTNAME -u MYSQL_USERNAME -p DATABASENAME > /PATH_TO_SAVE/BACKUP_NAME.sql

For example: sudo mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p magento > /Users/mymacbook/Downloads/db_back.sql

Terminal will ask you for password, use the mysql user password.

It works for me.